# First saturday for a selected month and year

Tags: php, datetime

How could I find the first Saturday for a given month and year (month & year selected by a calender)?  I am using PHP.

Answer (score 10):

Use this function:

```
<?php  
  /**
   *
   *  Gets the first weekday of that month and year
   *
   *  @param  int   The day of the week (0 = sunday, 1 = monday ... , 6 = saturday)
   *  @param  int   The month (if false use the current month)
   *  @param  int   The year (if false use the current year)
   *
   *  @return int   The timestamp of the first day of that month
   *
   **/  
  function get_first_day($day_number=1, $month=false, $year=false)
  {
    $month  = ($month === false) ? strftime("%m"): $month;
    $year   = ($year === false) ? strftime("%Y"): $year;

    $first_day = 1 + ((7+$day_number - strftime("%w", @mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year)))%7);

    return @mktime(0,0,0,$month, $first_day, $year);
  }

  // this will output the first saturday of january 2007 (Sat 06-01-2007)
  echo strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y", get_first_day(6, 1, 2007)); 
?>
```

Credits: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#77489)

---

**[EDIT]: Another short way:**

Use strtotime() like this:

```
$month = 1;
$year = 2007;

echo date('d/M/Y',strtotime('First Saturday '.date('F o', @mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year))));
```

This outputs:

```
06/Jan/2007
```

Comment: hi shamit bro.. first of all thx for ur reply. but in both cases its showing a warning like <b>Warning</b>:  mktime() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given ... i am entirely new to php so could u help me to sort out this.. thx.

Comment: @bsrreddy, I have updated both codes to suppress warnings. Try now.

Comment: hmm...code is working fine bro. but the result is not correct itseems. i selected 02-jan-2010 in my calender where this date is a first saturday of that month. but the result it showing is 03/Jan/2009 where it should be 02/jan/2009.

Comment: The functions are correct. Try to run them in a empty separate PHP code file. There must be some other problem in your code and calendar.

Comment: i am also thinking that there would be problem with calender.. let me check out and call you back brother. thank you.

Comment: hi.. i am sorry bro.. as i am very new i could not find the problem,,which causing all this fishy..shall i post all my content so that u can understand what exactly i want?

Comment: hi shamit gi..i need some calriffication.what is 'F o' doing below..plz explain me. echo date('d/M/Y',strtotime('First Saturday '.date('F o', @mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year))));

Comment: @bsreddy, `F o` are the *formatting options* for php function [`date`](http://php.net/date). The `F` is the full textual representation of month and `o` is the ordinal number of the year, thus effectively representiang the full string as "First Saturday January 2007".

Comment: oh..thx brother..finally thx alot for helping me. i checked through my calender and now ur function is working like a champ. thx. see u .

Answer (score 1):

Here is one-liner:

```
$firstSat = strtotime( 'first Saturday', strtotime( "$month $year" ) );
```

Test:

```
foreach( array("Jan","Feb","Nov","Dec" ) as $month)
{
   $year = '2017';
   echo "$month, $year";
   $firstSat = strtotime( 'first Saturday', strtotime( "$month $year" ) );
   $date = date( 'Y-M-d', $firstSat );
   echo " $firstSat $date <br>" ;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Jan, 2017 1483747200 2017-Jan-07
Feb, 2017 1486166400 2017-Feb-04
Nov, 2017 1509753600 2017-Nov-04
Dec, 2017 1512172800 2017-Dec-02
```