# trouble with php dates

Tags: php, date

I am trying to calculate, based on today's date (24 August 2012), the following three values:

1. Date of this month's first Saturday.
2. Date of this month's third Saturday.
3. Date of next month's first Saturday.

This is how I do it in PHP script:

```
// Returns August 2012
$this_month = date("F Y");

// Returns September 2012
$next_month = date("F Y", strtotime("next month"));

// Returns August 04th, Saturday
$t_sat_1st=date('U', strtotime($this_month.' First Saturday'));

// Returns August 18th, Saturday
$t_sat_3rd=date('U', strtotime($this_month.' Third Saturday'));

// Returns September 08th, Saturday
$n_sat_1st=date('U', strtotime($next_month.' First Saturday') );
```

Why is the wrong date returned for the last line of code? I expect it to return September 1st, 2012. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: what did it actually return you?

Comment: instead of September 1st, 2012?

Comment: @think123 it returned 8th of September 2012.

Comment: Try, in your date format, to use `o` instead of `Y`. And I'm assuming you've already looked at this, but maybe not? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682636/first-saturday-for-a-selected-month-and-year

Comment: @Nile using o, does nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: And what about the other solution posted? Also - try typing in a timestamp of the saturday and then using date() to get the week of the day to check and see that the server times are up-to-date.

Comment: are you running this on a server? because if you are, then the time will be set according to your server.

Comment: @think123 this is a hostmonster hosting I am running it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your code doesn't exactly work, must be the way it is parsed.. 
but try

```
$n_sat_1st=date('U', strtotime('first saturday of ' . $next_month) )
```

Note the 'of' it is necessary.
This code will only work in 5.3+

> It should be noted that apparently some of these strings only work in PHP 5.3 apparently, notably:
>
> "first day of this month" and "last day of this month" for example. 
>   According to information found on another website, the "xxx day of"
>   feature was added in PHP 5.3.

Comment on this page - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

I have tested this on both windows and ubuntu both php 5.3 and 5.4 and it works.

If this does not work, try this

```
 $d = new DateTime($next_month);
 $d->modify('first saturday of this month');
 echo $d->format('U');
```

Comment: The `of` is extraneous I think.

Comment: -1: Tested on my local machine. Did not return a different timestamp.

Comment: when I use `of`, the date returned is Dec 31st. If I remove `of` as @Nile suggests, I still get 8th of September.

Comment: I did this code on my server - echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first saturday of  ' . $next_month) )  Comes back with  2012-09-01. This is on a windows box php 5.4.6 'of' is required, if I leave out of it comes back as september eigth.

Comment: i've balanced this, didn't think the dv was necessary.

Comment: @Kris that line returns 1969-12-31 on hostmonster hosting. I am very confused.

Comment: I have updated my code with another solution, does that work? Also which PHP version are you using?

Comment: Yes, this one works! PHP Version 5.2.17. Do you know why this works as opposed to what I was using / your first suggestion? Is that a parsing issue?

Comment: If you look at the last comment on http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php it says that some of the formats are new in 5.3 So maybe this one does not exist in 5.2