# How to Get First Week Saturday date of current month in php?

Tags: php

how to get Saturday first week date of the current month...Actually I have two input data field first is **start date** and **second date** input what I am looking for
is **first start date** is always starts from every week on Saturday and submit report date is always next week Wednesday

First Start Date Input

```
$date=date('m/d/Y');
<input id="mock_test_date" name="start date" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"  
value="date('m/d/Y')" readonly="readonly" />
```

Second Date Input

```
<input id="mock_test_date" name="start date" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control"  value="date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date .' +4 day'))" readonly="readonly" />
```

how can I get the First Week Saturday on every month and on the second field I will get date of next Wednesday....if first input Saturday is on month end then i will get next month wednesday date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First saturday for a selected month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682636/first-saturday-for-a-selected-month-and-year)

Comment: i am looking for automatic not selected month and year

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `DateTimeImmutable` to get the next Saturday and the next Wednesday relatively to the already found Saturday:

```
$saturday = (new DateTimeImmutable)->modify('next Saturday');
$wednesday = $saturday->modify('next Wednesday');

var_dump(
    $saturday->format('D M j G:i:s T Y'),
    $wednesday->format('D M j G:i:s T Y')
);
```

The result would be:

```
string(27) "Sat Feb 22 0:00:00 EST 2020"
string(27) "Wed Feb 26 0:00:00 EST 2020"
```

Comment: how can i echo it as variable

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is being sought. An example would be helpful.
The solution with DateTime as I understand the question:

```
$firstSaturdayThisMonth = date_create('first Saturday of this Month');
$wednesdayAfterFirstSaturday = (clone $firstSaturdayThisMonth)->modify('next Wednesday');

echo $firstSaturdayThisMonth->format('D, j.M')
  ." - ".$wednesdayAfterFirstSaturday->format('D, j.M Y');
```

The result of today 19.02.2020:

```
Sat, 1.Feb - Wed, 5.Feb 2020
```